# How to convert an unformatted text file to JSON using NiFi

Tags: json, regex, apache-nifi

I have a file and using NiFi I need to change the data into JSON format.
My sample text data  (i have very large data):

```
{

    2121=0,
    710=-350
    711=21646343,-565:27055312343,#-4129:213,-345:
    715=-366,
    813=uhueairghubg,
    814=tsbb rgkjss
    815=
    816=fine on irea
    846=1
}
{

    331=92222930003
    335=went.srwfwr.rffarf
    336=4
    338=0
    354=1099r5834
    355=16777217
    358=0
    361=0
    364=1
    368=11
    373=1280;128;#3262
}
```

now I need to convert this data into proper JSON file data 
as below

```
[{

    "2121":"0",
    "710":"-350",

       "711":"215564446343,-800:27055312343,#-4129:215687174603,-800:",
    "715":"-366",
    "813":"uhueairghubg",
    "814":"tsbb rgkjss",
    "815":" ",
    "816":"fine on irea",
    "846":"1"
},
{

    "331":"9595930003",
    "335":"went.srwfwr.rffarf",
    "336":"4",
    "338":"0",
    "354":"1099r5834",
    "355":"16777217",
    "358":"0",
    "361":"0",
    "364":"1",
    "368":"11",
    "373":"180;18;#362"
}]
```

How can I replace these values in NiFi?

Comment: Your sample input already looks very close to JSON.  Are you sure that you don't already have the option to generate a proper JSON output?

Comment: Your Input and output don't match. Look at your input at first object, which has not the "711" field, but your output has! Or the value of field "335" in the input is different from the output.

Comment: @HamedGhasempour sorry I have updated the values it should be same values

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in some separate levels:

**Level 1:**
*Add quotes wrapper and convert `=` to `:`*

**pattern:**

```regex
([^\s]+?.*)=((.*(?=,$))+|.*).*
```

***replacement**

```regex
"$1":"$2"
```

***Sample:* [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JbCqPV/1)**

**Level2**
*Add comma at end of each string inside objects*

**pattern**

```regex
((}(?=\n{))|(\".*\":\".*\"))\n(?!})
```

**replacement**

```regex
$1,\n
```

***Sample:* [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dnL14F/1)**

**Level 3**
*Put a `[` in start and a `]` at end of your string*

Done.